# How to set width ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to set ElevatedButton width. I tried Wrap ElevatedButton with SizedBox set width and Width container but it didn't work. I also set the minimumSize in the ElevatedButton still can't change the width of the button. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        width: 20,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            elevation: 0.0,
            onPrimary: _buttonIsActive ? Colors.white : const Color(0xFF91A5B2),
            primary:
                _buttonIsActive ? Color(0xFF0E71B0) : const Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
            minimumSize: const Size(88, 56),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {}, //=> _addVital(), (Need Open)
          child: const Text('Update',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the button with Align widget, this will reduce the constraint.

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      elevation: 0.0,
      foregroundColor:
          _buttonIsActive ? Colors.white : const Color(0xFF91A5B2),
      backgroundColor:
          _buttonIsActive ? Color(0xFF0E71B0) : const Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
      minimumSize: const Size(88, 56),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {}, //=> _addVital(), (Need Open)
    child: const Text('Update',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
  ),
),
```

`onPrimary` and `primary` are deprecated.

Comment: Providing `alignment:` on Container will do the same

Answer (score 0):

```
 Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height:80,
                                    width: 300,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          foregroundColor: Colors.black
                                        ),
                                        onPressed:() {
                                        setState(() {
                                          showPopUp = true;
                                        });
                                        print("elevated button pressed");
                                      }, child: Text("Add Device")),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
```

1. wrap elevation button inside a container give height:90, width:300 (according to you ). 
   2)wrap this container inside Row()

[image]